# Bluetooth serial connection between Pi and MacOS Monterey on M1 Macbook both with builtin bluetooth

Tags: pi-4, bluetooth, serial

How do I connect a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1 to an M1 Macbook Pro 16" using rfcomm over a Bluetooth connection?

I'm able to connect the devices via Bluetooth but then not over the Bluetooth serial.

I want to be able to run a terminal over tty over Bluetooth

On pi:

Setting up Bluetooth:

https://howchoo.com/pi/bluetooth-raspberry-pi

Comment: Have you ever done this on a different computer? Have you ever heard of this being done? I'm not trying to be negative about the idea (it would be wonderful if it works), but I've not heard of this before. That could be that I'm too old to hear new thoughts, though.

Comment: Other's have done this on Intel Macs

Comment: https://howchoo.com/pi/bluetooth-raspberry-pi